# ${\cal O}(1)$ approximation of $s$-channel scattering amplitude

Tags: quantum-field-theory, kinematics, correlation-functions

I am trying to reproduce the calculation shown in the image (taken from Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model by Schwartz) and I could not, for the life of me, understand how to perform this $\mathcal{O(1)}$ approximation.

To further explain, in this chapter 29.2, they calculate the $s$-channel scattering amplitude which results in the expression given by:

$i\mathcal{M}_s = (ie \cot{\theta})^2 {\varepsilon_1}^{\mu}{\varepsilon_2}^{\nu}{\varepsilon_3 ^{*}}^{\alpha}{\varepsilon_4 ^{*}}^{\beta} \dots$

They then move on to approximate it somehow and obtain the expression given by:

$\mathcal{M}_s = \frac{e^2 \cot^2{\theta}}{4m_w ^2 m_z ^2}[2su + s^2 + \dots + \mathcal{O}(1)]$.

If someone here could help shed some light on how to go from the first expression to the second one, I would appreciate it!

[image]

Comment: It's not an approximation: it means that he ignored constant terms (terms that do not depend on energy/momentum).

Answer (score 0):

Expansion, approximation, call it whatever you wish. Make sure you appreciate the *context* of the calculation! He is uninterested in the actual answer, but only in the *"dangerous"* terms growing with energy to violate perturbative unitarity.

He is examining the *E* behavior of the amplitude, as he is expressly specifying, quite clearly.  In  your calculation, ignore anything not growing with *E*, what he calls $O(1)$, the "uninteresting, safe" part of the answer.

You  observe that *s,t,u* grow with *E*, generically, except for their sum, a fact he uses, so he broadly keeps *them*. This is the theme of his subsequent calculation, leading to his punchline, (29.27), which made quite a splash at the time of its discovery, encouraging a large number of physicists to take the the actual Higgs ***particle*** seriously, sight unseen.